# Command for displaying the error in MS COBOL

Tags: cobol85

Can i ask some help about the ms cobol 2.20?. I found difficulty in reading the error when
i got run-time in my program because it was covered by the path of my directory where my
program resides.Is this possible to log this in notepad?so that i can clearly see what the
error is.

Something like this.

```
           C:\FOLDR1\FOLDR2\FOLDR3\FOLDR4\FOLDR5\ER,LINE:0094
```

As so you can see in the last it's an error in my program.
can you help me on this.
Thank you.

Comment: I want to upvote this just because you had the guts to ask a COBOL question on this site. There are not many...

Comment: thank you,but do you know the answer for my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue. But give it an hour, maybe someone will. As for troubleshooting, is the path output from your program? If so, can you just turn it off and then be able to read the error message? Failing that, can you add a linefeed before the path so that it does not hide the output? Lastly, can you redirect the error to a file, then you would not have this issue?

Comment: how can i redirect my error into a file?you mean that i can log the error in the notepad?if so, how to do this?

Comment: For info about Windows command redirection, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx

Comment: If you are still working on this, can you post your whole source code here? It might help a diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

You might get a more meaningful error message if you try to compile your Cobol program in OpenCobol (see www.opencobol.org).

Alternately, you could try commenting out your procedure division from the bottom up one paragraph at a time until the error message goes away.  Then, at least, you would know where the problem is.  You could post here the paragraph where the error occurs for us to opine on.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, we're talking about a run-time error, not a compile-time one.

Comment: @DavidGorsline,yes i am referring to run-time error.that's my problem when i execute this comand cobol myprogram..it says run-time error and the problem is i cannot see the error because it is covered by the path of which my program resides.as you can see in my post.please help me on this...thank you.